# Layer bending with first layer not sticking

Tags: creality-ender-3, adhesion

I'm pretty new to 3D printing, so I'm looking for some tips with following problem I have.
I'm trying to print following model https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:4671256 on my Ender 3 v2.

But as soon as the print reaches the body and the first layer parts are attached, the print comes loose from the bed and the print will be dragged by the nozzle.
If you look at the picture you can see the bending of the front paws of the sculpture. So they don't stay sticked onto the bed.

I have changed the model to be 80 % in size, but also upped the bed temperature from 50 to 75 °C.
Running at 50 °C was even worse...

My printed 20x20x20 mm test cube was flawless by the way.

[image]

Comment: You've got an adhesion problem, there are plenty similar questions to find. Other than the bed temperature you could add a brim or add an adhesive.

Comment: @0scar true, but I also see lack of support in that area - there should some support structures already supporting in that area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a Brim (the model is rather tricky on FDM), which can help with bad adhesion.
Your first laser appears coarse and not "smooched" as it should. This hints that you leveled either high, or you hit the portal off-angle. If it is just high leveling, a tiny turn "up" can help a lot.

The model has some rather flat overhangs, like the mouth, chin, under the tails and lower body. I suggest printing that with support turned on.

For PLA Filament, I use 200°C nozzle with 60°C bed, so unless you go far beyond that, your print should work.

Last words: that the model you chose was made with resin printing in mind, so you will use some details.

Comment: Thanks for the details @Trish ! I will first try the easiest part and change the model to have a brim added to see what happens. And I will read up on the rest of the suggestions.

Comment: Brim  *and* support together are the easiest, both are slicer settings.

Comment: Brim alone did the trick for this model, worked out nice. Again thx for the tips.